# Checklist when moving from Heroku to AWS

Tags: heroku, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to move my backend API app (node.js express server) from Heroku to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. But I did not realize the amount of features that Heroku was providing automatically and which I now have to set up manually in AWS.
So here is the list of features which I discovered were missing in AWS and the solutions I have implemented.
Could you please let me know if I am missing something in order to run smoothly my APIs in AWS and get the equivalent of what I had in Heroku?

- **auto-restart server when crashed :** I am using PM2 to automatically restart my server in case of critical error
- **SSL certificate :** I am using AWS ACM certificate,
- **logging :**  have inserted the datadog agent in order to receive logs in datadog
- **logging response time :** I have added the "morgan-body" package to get each requests' duration and response code (had to manually filter the AWS healthchecks and search engine bots, because AWS gave me an IP adress which was visited constatntly by Baidu bots)
- **server timeout :** I have implemented a 1200000ms timeout on the whole app (any better option ?)
- **auto deploy from Github :**  I have implemented a github automation to deploy code automatically (better options?)

Am I missing something? This app is already live so I do not want to put my customers at risk when I will move from Heroku to AWS...
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are covered:

- Heroku Dynos restart after crashing or raising an error ([Heroku Restarting Policy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting))
- SSL certificates are provided for free
- logging: Heroku supports various plugins, including Datadog
- response time (in millisec) is logged automatically
- HTTP timeout is 30 sec (it cannot be changed)
- deploy from Github is possible (connecting the accounts), Docker deployment is also supported. **Better options?** Using Github Actions to deploy a new version after code push or tagging.

If you are migrating a production environment I strongly suggest first to setup a Heroku (Free) Dyno to test and verify all your needs are satisfied.

Comment: Thank you @Beppe C but my question was rather the opposite : how to migrate securely from Heroku to AWS?